# SMS Service that uses +44 7781 470659

Tags: authentication, sms

I'm trying to figure out what SMS API Service many of the major online services are using for 2 factor authentication (Dropbox, Microsoft, Yahoo, eBay, Blizzard, Steam etc...)

SMS Messages are coming from +44 7781 470659.

I've spent several hours googling for the answer, to no avail. Anyone with experience using SMS APIs happen to recognise it?

Comment: Yeah, you can add NameCheap to that list as well. I'm thinking it may be a global SMS provider such as SMSGlobal or similar.

Comment: hey - thanks for the upvote - I thought this question was well and truly dead - I've spent hours trying to figure out who they all use - still not sure

Comment: Likely a company called clickatell, a large SMS broker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clickatell

Answer (score 5):

Seems like legit SMS "broker" who sends out large-scale text messages on behalf of many companies. Microsoft, eBay, Google, Yahoo, the list goes on. However, it's very easy to spoof the sending number, and while the real number is legit, there are reports of scammers spoofing it for nefarious reasons, asking for info, trying to scam you.

This phone number was discussed here as used for ebay: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/2dr4sl/received_text_from_microsoft_about_a_singleuse/

Also here this number was used for google:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail-es/c7UUBpkgTSA/Y3Shun9SeNkJ

**UPD.** [Guys from Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/osecurity-oinfosafe/is-44-7781-470-659-a-legitimate-phone-number/a0896a7c-3c98-4fe1-962c-445f5840c6d2) say that it is [Sure (Guernsey) network](https://web.sure.com/guernsey).

Comment: yes - I've personally received legitimate messages for several services, but I'm struggling to nail down who the broker actually is

Comment: @MattBolt is not Microsoft a credible source?

Comment: I think you'll find he's not actually from Microsoft, just a resident moderator. I have seen "Sure Guernsey" a couple of places in my searching. I'm trying to contact them and see if they offer SMS as a service - unfortunately their website doesn't advertise an off the shelf api / service. If they turn out to actually be the one, I'll be sure to get your points - but they may just be a carrier used by another service.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the actual SMS service provider is SMS Gateway (Europe) from CM Telecom, The Netherlands. Microsoft, Facebook, Ikea, AirBnB, McDonald's, WhatsApp, DHL, and BMW are listed as their customers. They have SMS Gateway service in Europe, Asia, Africa, North America, and South America. Pretty global.

https://www.smsgateway.to/en/europe

Answer (score 0):

It supposedly belongs to Sure as stated above, but Microsoft officials don't appear to have said that. It seems that regular users of the forum said that.

According to this http://www.scamnumbers.info/shownumber.php?number=447781470659 the number has bounced around and has been used by scammers as recently as July 2016!!! I have texts from Adobe, Microsoft, and ebay dating back to December 2015 from this number, though. It supposedly now belongs to Sure, though. Who knows. It is very disconcerting!